# How overcome error 400 in Watson Discovery Upload Data

Tags: watson-discovery

I am new to IBM cloud. I deleted my Watson Discovery service by mistake. Afterwards, I re-created a new service and there was no issue. But when I try to upload data to Watson Discovery, I'm given error 400 "Only one free environment is allowed per resource group". I'm on the Lite plan.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login into your ibm cloud account and go to https://cloud.ibm.com/shell and run the following commands

```
ibmcloud resource reclamations
```

the above command list all resource reclamations under your account. to know which resource to delete check the Entity CRN and copy it's ID then use below command to delete the resource

```
ibmcloud resource reclamation-delete [ID]  --force
```

Replace the ID with resource id to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late, but I found some information under this link: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/discovery?topic=discovery-gs-api. 
It mentions something like: "If you have recently deleted a Lite instance and then receive a 400 - Only one free environment is allowed per resource group error message when creating a new environment in a new Lite instance, you need to finish deleting the original Lite instance. See ibmcloud resource reclamations and follow the reclamation-delete instructions."

Also further information can be gathered from here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cloud-cli-ibmcloud_commands_resource#ibmcloud_resource_reclamations